# Loading My Custom OS from USB flash drive

Tags: operating-systems, kernel, bootstrap, usb, bios

Suppose I want to create a portable OS, that needs a USB flash drive only to work. and i wrote my boatloader in the first sector to be loaded by the BIOS, from here on, what can I do to load my OS kernel, which is located somewhere in a USB drive?

Comment: You can make the bootloader load the kernel into memory, then start executing it.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/).  It certainly isn't related to **programming**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make BIOS calls from your loaded bootloader.  I don't think the BIOS knows about file systems, so you'd have to provide code (i.e. write a file system reader) for that in terms of reading sectors, depending on how your bootloader is intended to find your OS kernel code.  You would probably use `02h Read Sectors`, or maybe `42h    Extended Read Sectors` BIOS calls.

Check out [BIOS calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call).

---

You might also check out [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), which is much more modern, as BIOS is being superseded with that.  Even if you don't use UEFI, there's some good discussion about BIOS and its limitations there.

Comment: thank's that's the answer i was looking for, so it's up to the BIOS to handle the USB transactions and do all the stuff, in my side it doesn't matter whether my OS is in a flash drive or hard drive, or a floppy disk, as far as I'm using the BIOS.

Comment: I think that the BIOS may handle drives over USB, but I don't know for sure.  If it does handle USB, it probably still won't support ports having USB 3.0, though, even at the lower speeds of USB <=2.0, because it's different hardware.